# Updated Rich Text Editor not available in Winter 15 Org

Tags: richtextarea, winter15

As per the Winter 15 release notes the rich text editor in the rich text field should get updated with the new features. But it seems i am only getting the updated editor on Article object. On account object i created a rich text field but it shows old one only.

OLD editor :
[image: Old Tool Bar]

NEW editor :
[image: New Tool bar]

Am i missing something here ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What about now? Also, if the answer helped, please accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Per the release notes:

> The rich text editor lets users quickly and easily format text in rich
>   text fields and in tools such as the Knowledge article editor,
>   questions in Chatter Answers, and the Case Feed Email action.

It looks like it is only going to be available initially on those areas for Winter 15.